# Outlook Custom Search folder for Color categories

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, colors

I want to create a custom search folder in my outlook 2010 containing all emails marked with Red color category. But new custom folder->create a new custom folder->criteria->More choices not showing  me color category options.

How I can create a search folder based upon the color category?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I display categories in Outlook's sidebar?](https://superuser.com/questions/1228870/how-can-i-display-categories-in-outlooks-sidebar)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to create a search folder for a category, is to right click a mail that is categorized with the chosen category, selecting the categorize option and then select the [Open "category name" search folder] option.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Outlook search box.
Type the following text: category:="your category name"
For example; I have a category named 'in progress'
So, I would type category:="in progress"
Result would list all email that's categorized "in progress"