# How can I display categories in Outlook's sidebar?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, sidebar

The sidebar in Microsoft Outlook 2010 displays a list of user-created email folders.  I rarely use folders in Outlook, as I find organizing my inbox using [categories](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-assign-color-categories-A1FDE97E-15E1-4179-A1A0-8A91EF89B8DC) to be much simpler.

**Is it possible to display a list of categories on the sidebar in Outlook?**

[image: Outlook 2010 sidebar]

Answer (score 10):

You can create custom search folders based on categories to organize emails. Not sure how efficient this is with a large amount of mail.

Use one of the following to create custom search folder:

- Under the **Folder** tab in Outlook, click **New Search
  Folder**
- Use the keyboard shortcut **CTRL+SHIFT+P**
- In the sidebar of the folder hierarchy, you should have a folder
  called **Search Folders**, right click on it to get
  the **New Search Folder** option

[Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-messages-or-items-with-a-Search-Folder-24e1a8e4-dfb6-4662-bf37-ea769925f094) is the Microsoft documentation on creating them for Outlook 2010.

Comment: How would I create custom search folders?

Comment: Can you summarize the relevant information in your answer? Typically links should [not be used as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/351462).

Comment: Although I am using Office 365 in 2022 and not Outlook 2010, your **Ctrl+Shit+P** solution allowed me to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: So basically, you have to drag folders around in the same Folders panel on the left. You can create manual folders by right clicking there, or you can create an automatic folder called a Search Folder. In that dialog, you have 2 options for Categories: You can choose `Organizing Mail->Categorized mail` and then at the bottom choose the categories you want, or you can create a custom search folder (with more options) and select custom criteria - in particular, `More Choices->Categories`. The latter option is more clicks but also more customizable options.